# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing a problem 
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
in laravel.
I used DB:: and Join and where
give me

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $jobs =DB::table('jobs')->where('is_approved',true)
     ->join('countries','jobs.country_id','countries.id')
     ->join('job_types','jobs.job_type_id','job_types.id')
     ->select('jobs.*','countries.countryname','job_types.job_type')
     ->first(); 
     $category=categories::all();
     $countries=country::all();
    return view('front.home.homeContant',   compact('jobs','category','countries'));
}
```

View

```
@forelse($jobs as $job)
            <a href="{{url('/job-details',$job->id)}}" class="job-listing">
                <!-- Job Listing Details -->
                <div class="job-listing-details">
                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <div class="job-listing-company-logo">
                        <img src="{{ asset('front') }}/images/EETLogo.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Details -->
                    <div class="job-listing-description">
                        <h3 class="job-listing-title">{{ $job->title }}</h3>
                        <!-- Job Listing Footer -->
                        <div class="job-listing-footer">
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="icon-material-outline-location-on"></i>{{ $job->countryname }}</li>
                                <li><i class="icon-material-outline-business-center"></i> {{ $job->Job_Type }}</li>
                                <li><i class="icon-material-outline-access-time"></i><?php echo \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($job->created_at))->diffForHumans() ?></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Bookmark -->
                    <span class="list-apply-button ripple-effect">Apply Now</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            @empty
            <div class="job-listing-description">
              <h3 class="job-listing-title">No Jobs Found</h3>
            </div>  
            @endforelse
```

I used Get() but it's gives me ampty array

```
$jobs = DB::table('jobs')
 ->join('countries','jobs.country_id','countries.id')
 ->join('job_types','jobs.job_type_id','job_types.id')
 ->select('jobs.*','countries.countryname','job_types.job_type')
 ->where('is_approved',true)
 ->get();
```

When I delete

```
->join('job_types','jobs.job_type_id','job_types.id')
```

It's working very well

Comment: You use `first()` so $jobs is probably a single job object, not an array of jobs.

Comment: There is a very useful laravel debug called `dd`

Comment: @Jonnix can I use Get() in this case

Comment: @HimaHima Give it a try.

Comment: @Jonnix it's give me empty array No Jobs Found

Comment: @Omi I'll try thanks

Comment: @HimaHima Add your updated code to the question please.

Comment: $jobs = DB::table('jobs')
     ->join('countries','jobs.country_id','countries.id')
     ->join('job_types','jobs.job_type_id','job_types.id')
     ->select('jobs.*','countries.countryname','job_types.job_type')
     ->where('is_approved',true)
     ->get();

Comment: Maybe you don't have any that are approved? Unsure.

Comment: @Jonnix All of jobs approved :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using **first()** which gives a model instance or stdObject. You can not loop them. You need to use **get().**

```
$jobs = DB::table('jobs')
     ->join('countries','jobs.country_id','countries.id')
     ->join('job_types','jobs.job_type_id','job_types.id')
     ->select('jobs.*','countries.countryname','job_types.job_type')
     ->where('is_approved',true)
     ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm trying to use get() but it's give me empty array No Jobs Found

Comment: Do you have rows in your table? use dd($jobs) in your controller to check if there is some value.

Comment: hassan   When I delete

->join('job_types','jobs.job_type_id','job_types.id')

It's working very well

Comment: Then maybe there are some issues joining the two tables. Double check the foreign key in jobs table and check value matches in both tables.

Comment: Thank you I'll check now

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your kindly help
the problem solved when I change

```
->select('jobs.*','countries.countryname','job_types.job_type')
```

to

```
->select('jobs.*','countries.countryname','job_types.Job_Type')
```

I just capitalized

> Job_Types

I don't know why I must capitalize it, but finally, it's worked.